# cocoa memory management question

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, memory-management

I am in an argument with a friend who says that I have to put autorelase here:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://origin-www.metrolyrics.com/api/widgets/mac/seeker.php"] autorelease];
```

But isn't the object automatically autoreleased when it was send to me from NSURL class method? Thanks.

Comment: Get your friend to put $20 where his mouth is. Then code it up his way and watch it crash. Use the Build & Analyze command and keep his bill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. you did **not** allocate or copy an object so you do **not** have to release it. Just use your code without the autorelease. ;-)

The Class method you used looks like this: (Normally it does. We can't know it, because Apple doesn't share the code.)

```
+(id)URLWithString:(NSString *)aString {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithString:aString] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: +1 And to make more explicit, you **must not** call `autorelease` here. It is not optional; it is not permitted. The above code will almost certainly crash.

Answer (score 5):

This is the rule:

If you invoke a method that returns an object and:

- begins with `new`
- begins with `alloc`
- is `retain`
- contains `copy`

then you are responsible for releasing (or autoreleasing) the returned object.  The *only* time this would not be the case is if the documentation says otherwise.  You may also see in the header files that the method is annotated with the `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` macro.  (The header file counts as documentation)

An easy way to remember this is "NARC" (new-alloc-retain-copy).

In your example, since `URLWithString:` does not begin with `new` or `alloc`, does not contain `copy`, and is not `retain`, then you **must not** release the returned object.  Doing so is a violation of the memory management guidelines and will cause your app to crash (unless you're doing something stupid elsewhere).